# Как удалить колонку grid программно по номеру?

Tags: c#, framework, wpf, .net

Grid c множеством колонок и столбцов - они создаются динамически(пользователь вводит их количество и колонки и столбцы программно создаются.), соответственно у них нет названий. Т.е. как удалить программно колонку в grid зная её номар?

Comment: Если вам нужно добавление/удаление столбцов, `Grid` не самый удобный контейнер. Возьмите лучше что-нибудь производное от `ItemsControl` и управляйте через `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Опишите уже всю задачу целиком. Что вы хотите сделать, а тут Вам уже посоветуют на каком фреймворке это сделать лучше

Comment: Ну мне нужно сделать, что то вроде шахмат, только размер доски(кол-во клеток) будет указываться пользователем, а сами клетки будут иметьформу 8-угольника. При этом ширина и высота поля не будут привышать 100 элементов. Вот я и решил изначально в XAML создать разметку в grid создать 100 столбцов и 100 строк, в каждое поле положить по нарисованному 8-угольнику и внужных 8 угольниках разместить фигуры. Далее хочу, что бы когда пользователь вводил ныжное ему кол-во столбцов и строк игрового поля, то удалять ненужные строки и стролбцы вместе с содержимым.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так вот:

```
Наш_Grid.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt(index);
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?